# Derive a 3x3 matrix A from General solution x and right hand side b?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I derive a 3x3 matrix A from General solution x and right hand side b?

Eg. Ax=b= $\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\2 \end{pmatrix}$

General solution for x is
$\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}+c\begin {pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+d\begin {pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},\ c, d \in \Bbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You know $Ax$ for three vectors $x$.  Put those columns together and you get a matrix $B$ for which you know $AB$.  If $AB = C$ (and $B$ is invertible), then $A = CB^{-1}$.